# Create a list containing specific data R

Tags: r, list, nested

The following are two list nested within a bigger list.

I want to create a new list(I assume this is the best output, but other suggestions are welcome!) that only has the data relating to malaria.

I have no code to share as I have no idea how to do this! Thanks in advance.

```
list(structure(c("Condition", "Malnutrition", "Anaemia", "Pneumonia", 
"Uncomplicated malaria", "Diarrhoea with Blood", "Other diarrhea", 
"Total", "2001", "118", "243", "1592", "4969", "134", "423", 
"7479", "2002", "9927", "18933", "98068", "302891", "21724", 
"48610", "500153", "2003", "7232", "18933", "68418", "227034", 
"13369", "35083", "370069", "2004", "6896", "98068", "74769", 
"215533", "12198", "46265", "453729", "Total", "334156", "136177", 
"242847", "750426", "47425", "130381", "1641412"), .Dim = c(8L, 
6L)), 
structure(c("Condition", "Uncomplicated malaria", "Diarrhoea with Blood", 
"Other diarrhea", "Pneumonia", "Hypertension", "Diabetes", "Cataracts", 
"Asthma", "Scabies", "Mental Disorder", "2001", "209182", "7306", 
"12800", "27832", "13573", "231", "614", "2857", "15596", "1326", 
"2002", "264785", "17662", "27739", "54454", "24759", "1009", 
"1092", "7470", "43741", "2298", "2003", "227034", "8225", "2003", 
"38233", "18790", "551", "526", "5819", "22077", "1627", "2004", 
"215533", "7605", "2004", "41128", "23329", "690", "834", "5583", 
"23784", "1954", "Total", "916534", "40798", "44546", "161647", 
"80451", "2481", "3066", "21729", "105198", "7205"), .Dim = c(11L, 
6L))
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish what is the end goal?

Comment: an option would be `lapply(list, function(x) x[grepl("malaria", x[,1]),, drop = FALSE])`

Comment: I want to create a table with the first column being the type of malaria (is this case only uncomplicated malaria is shown) and then the next columns will be the number of cases per region.

Comment: Missuse that is exactly what i want! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** based on op feedback:

Looking at your example first we need to trasform each `list` element in a `data.frame` with the correct `colnames`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

col_names_list <- lapply(dat, function(x) x[1, ]) # we extract the first row (colnames)

dat <- lapply(dat, function(x) as.data.frame(x[-1, ])) # change to data.frame format

dat <- map2(dat, col_names_list, function(x,y) {colnames(x)[1] <- y[1] 
                                                x}) 
# change the colname in data.frame only for the first column (named "Condition")
```

With `map` we can then extract what we need:

```
dat %>% 
  map(function(x) x[grepl("malaria", x[,1]),, drop = FALSE])

# [[1]]
# Condition 2001   2002   2003   2004  Total
# 4 Uncomplicated malaria 4969 302891 227034 215533 750426
# 
# [[2]]
# Condition   2001   2002   2003   2004  Total
# 1 Uncomplicated malaria 209182 264785 227034 215533 916534
```

Data used:

```
dat <- list(structure(c("Condition", "Malnutrition", "Anaemia", "Pneumonia", 
                 "Uncomplicated malaria", "Diarrhoea with Blood", "Other diarrhea", 
                 "Total", "2001", "118", "243", "1592", "4969", "134", "423", 
                 "7479", "2002", "9927", "18933", "98068", "302891", "21724", 
                 "48610", "500153", "2003", "7232", "18933", "68418", "227034", 
                 "13369", "35083", "370069", "2004", "6896", "98068", "74769", 
                 "215533", "12198", "46265", "453729", "Total", "334156", "136177", 
                 "242847", "750426", "47425", "130381", "1641412"), .Dim = c(8L, 
                                                                             6L)), 
     structure(c("Condition", "Uncomplicated malaria", "Diarrhoea with Blood", 
                 "Other diarrhea", "Pneumonia", "Hypertension", "Diabetes", "Cataracts", 
                 "Asthma", "Scabies", "Mental Disorder", "2001", "209182", "7306", 
                 "12800", "27832", "13573", "231", "614", "2857", "15596", "1326", 
                 "2002", "264785", "17662", "27739", "54454", "24759", "1009", 
                 "1092", "7470", "43741", "2298", "2003", "227034", "8225", "2003", 
                 "38233", "18790", "551", "526", "5819", "22077", "1627", "2004", 
                 "215533", "7605", "2004", "41128", "23329", "690", "834", "5583", 
                 "23784", "1954", "Total", "916534", "40798", "44546", "161647", 
                 "80451", "2481", "3066", "21729", "105198", "7205"), .Dim = c(11L, 
                                                                               6L)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The actual data I am using is in a very large list with 9 elements and it is giving me  

Error in x[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Did you correctly change every elemen in the list `as.data.frame`? They need to have the same structure

Comment: When I try to do that I get the error: arguments imply differing number of rows.

Comment: Can you try now? See my update. Keep in mind that I'm using your `dput` as an example, if your actual date looks like it, you shouldn't have problems. Even with more elements

Comment: As long as the structure is the same.

Comment: It is a small part of my data but i think the structure is the same. The first two lines work if I say which element to use. However the third line has the error

Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [36] must be the same length as the vector [1] 

Code: 
`col_names_list <- lapply(dat[[1]], function(x) x[,1]) # we extract the first row (colnames)
 dat <- lapply(dat[[1]], function(x) as.data.frame(x[-1, ]))
 dat <- map2(dat, col_names_list, function(x,y) {colnames(x) <- y 
 x})'`

Comment: Probably each element in the list doesn't have the same length for the first row, which I'm using for the colnames

Comment: In your example each element in list has 6 columns, does this pattern continue for all the elements?

Comment: I have jsut checked and no it does not.

Comment: I'm sorry for this, would it be possible to see the actual data?

Comment: There is a lot of it! What is the best way to show you? It is made up of 3 lists with list lengths of 38, 117 an 101

Comment: after the first two lines, can you run this `lapply(dat, dim)`? and be sure that in each list the second values is always six? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The values are all different

Comment: `list(c(9L, 5L), c(35L, 1L), c(42L, 1L), c(39L, 10L), c(36L, 9L
), c(40L, 1L), c(38L, 10L), c(39L, 11L), c(35L, 6L), c(36L, 8L
), c(38L, 1L), c(38L, 1L), c(36L, 9L), c(35L, 1L), c(6L, 4L), 
    c(7L, 6L), c(7L, 6L), c(14L, 3L), c(14L, 3L), c(26L, 4L), 
    c(6L, 8L), c(11L, 9L), c(33L, 9L), c(9L, 8L), c(3L, 8L), 
    c(7L, 14L), c(4L, 8L), c(22L, 5L), c(11L, 9L), c(11L, 8L), 
    c(15L, 8L), c(2L, 9L), c(3L, 8L), c(9L, 9L), c(38L, 3L), 
    c(12L, 3L), c(8L, 3L), c(7L, 3L))`

Comment: That's where the problem is, see my update, now it should work.

Comment: I changed the 3rd line just to rename only the first column

Comment: This works perfectly. This is my last question: is there a way to also have the name for each of the column headings? At the moment they are just NA

Comment: I think that the problem is that they have different lengths, but I'm not sure. I'll udpdate if I can find a solution, otherwise feel free to open a new question. In the mean time, if the answer pleases you, feel free to upvote or accept it. Thanks.